# How can I ensure postgresql records are between given start and end times when some are midnight?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of venues

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: venues
#
#  id                          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                        :string           default(""), not null
#  address_1                   :string           default(""), not null
#  address_2                   :string
#  city                        :string           default(""), not null
#  county                      :string           default(""), not null
#  postal_code                 :string           default(""), not null
#  mon_start                   :time
#  mon_end                     :time
#  tue_start                   :time
#  tue_end                     :time
#  wed_start                   :time
#  wed_end                     :time
#  thu_start                   :time
#  thu_end                     :time
#  fri_start                   :time
#  fri_end                     :time
#  sat_start                   :time
#  sat_end                     :time
#  sun_start                   :time
#  sun_end                     :time
#  created_at                  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                  :datetime         not null
```

Some of the venues close time is after midnight, and some close before midnight.

I want to find all venues that are currently open, in relation to the time `now()`

### First attempt

```
SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE (mon_start <= now()::time AND mon_end > now()::time)
```

This doesn't return records if `mon_end` is after midnight.

### Second attempt

```
SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE (mon_start <= now()::time AND mon_end + interval '1 day' > now()::time)
```

But this still doesn't return records if `mon_end` is after midnight.

### Question

How can I select all venues where the `mon_start` is less than the time now, and the `mon_end` is greater than the time now.

e.g. **Mon start:** *4pm* **Mon end:** *1am* **Now:** *11:30pm*

### Bonus Question

Is there a way for me to query the correct column based on the current day name?

e.g. If today is wednesday, search on `wed_start` and `wed_end`

Comment: The problem with bonus question is if `Wed 0:50 am` will you search on `wed_start` or `tue_start`?

Comment: Good point! I hadn't thought that far ahead

Answer (score 1):

You need work with `DATE`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/SYRPW27409)**

```
WITH time_table as (
    SELECT '10:30pm'::time as open_time, '01:30am'::time close_time
    UNION
    SELECT '09:00pm'::time as open_time, '11:30pm'::time close_time
)
SELECT open_time, close_time, now(),
       now()::date + open_time as open_time,
       CASE WHEN close_time > open_time
            THEN now()::date + close_time
            ELSE now()::date + close_time + INTERVAL '1 day'
       END as close_time
FROM time_table
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]